# Java calculating past date from today is going into the future

Tags: java, datetime

I'm having an issue in Java calculating the current date minus a certain amount of days.

I have:

```
Date pastDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 25));
```

This is returning *Tue Feb 16 09:04:18 EST 2016* when it should actually return *Tue Dec 28 16:06:11 EST 2015* (25 days into the past).

What's very strange is that for any number under 25 days works completely fine:

```
Date pastDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 24));
```

As in 24 days into the past returns a predictable *Tue Dec 29 16:06:11 EST 2015*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you go over the [new data-time tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `24` days, the product remains just below the maximum possible `int` value, [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE), which is 2,147,483,647.  The `24` days product is 2,073,600,000.  The `25` days product is 2,160,000,000.  The result is overflow and a negative number, resulting in a date in the future.

For such values, use a `long` literal for the first value (or cast it to a `long`) to avoid the overflow that comes with exceeding `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Note the `L` appended to `1000L`:

```
(1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 25)
```

This works fine because the [desired constructor for `Date` takes a `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-).

Date arithmetic is handled more cleanly by using `Calendar`s, where you can explicitly `add` a negative number of days.

Also, with Java 8+, you can use [`Instant` and its `minus` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) to subtract the time.

```
Instant.now().minus(24, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Comment: Oh wow, what a quirky error. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time. Works perfectly now :).

Comment: If you're doing arithmetic based on a number of seconds or nanoseconds, you could potentially run into issues with leap seconds as well...due to leap seconds, the number of seconds in each day isn't always the same.

Answer (score 3):

Do not roll your own date-time calculations. Date-time work is a surprisingly tricky business. You have already run into the common `int`-versus-`long` error with calculation of milliseconds. Use a decent date-time library. Fortunately Java now comes with the industry’s best such library.

## java.time

As mentioned in [the correct Answer by rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956074/642706), you should be using the new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are notoriously troublesome.

Basics of java.time… An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC. Apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Time zone is crucial in determining dates, as the date is not the same around the world at any one moment. A new day dawns earlier in the east.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now(); // In UTC.
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
ZonedDateTime zdtTwentyFiveDaysAgo = zdt.minusDays( 25 );
```

You may want the first moment of the day for that date-time of 25 days ago rather then the current time-of-day. The first moment is not always `00:00:00.0` because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and perhaps other anomalies. So let java.time determine the time-of-day. We have to go through [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and then back to `ZonedDateTime` to get the first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTwentyFiveDaysAgoStart = zdtTwentyFiveDaysAgo.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```